# Match a line if there is something before a group of characters, at the start of the line

Tags: python, regex

I am looking to check against a line that matches the regex pattern below (emojis that are used in this format `:laugh:`), but I want to check if that pattern has anything before it, at the start of the line. In other words, I am trying to enforce that an emoji must be placed at the start of a line (only when there is an emoji on the line).

The regex I have already.

```
:[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+:
```

Example that must match:

- `randomstuff :laugh:` or any kind of string before the emoji

It should not match:

- `:laugh:`
- `:laugh: random`
- `random text without emoji`

I can't use any programming specific features, as this is for [Reddit's AutoModerator](https://www.reddit.com/wiki/automoderator/full-documentation) config.

Comment: Do you mean `.+:[a-...`?

Comment: What about leading spaces? Try `^[^:]+:[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+:` or `^.+:[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+:` if they should not prevent the match. Or, try `^\s*\S.*:[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+:` if a single non-whitespace char is required before the emoticon. See https://regex101.com/r/9wdunV/1

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 that's just escaping the character, I've removed it now. sorry.

Comment: Look at the first two characters, `.+`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 huh, I thought I have to use some weird look around. I think this works. Silly me making everything more complicated.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I feel stupid haha. thanks a bunch regardless.